# Is it possible to set of frames as a animated image and set it as abackground for Relative layout

Tags: android

I wrote the code for animated image and try to set it as a background for the relative layout but it is not working It is showing only one image not the animated image.

```
package com.example.animation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 //ImageView view;
 AnimationDrawable frameanimation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        RelativeLayout layout1=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);

        // Setting animation_list.xml as the background of the image view
           layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);

        // Type casting the Animation drawable
        frameanimation = (AnimationDrawable) layout1.getBackground();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also call `frameanimation.start();` after get AnimationDrawable,

like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout1=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);

// Setting animation_list.xml as the background of the image view
layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);

// Type casting the Animation drawable
frameanimation = (AnimationDrawable) layout1.getBackground();
frameanimation.start();
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I just forgot.